# Thread still waiting

Tags: java

```
public class Communicate {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Producer prod = new Producer();
        Consumer cons = new Consumer(prod);

        Thread pThread = new Thread(prod, "ProducerThread");
        Thread cThread = new Thread(cons, "ConsumerThread");

        pThread.start();
        cThread.start();
    }
}
class Producer extends Thread {

    StringBuffer sb;
    Producer() {                        //constructor
        sb = new StringBuffer();        //allot memory 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (sb) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                try {
                    sb.append("daksh    ");
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    System.out.println("appending " + i);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                }
            }//end of loop

            //data production is over, so notify Consumer Thread
            System.out.println("Done production");
            sb.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

class Consumer extends Thread {

    Producer prod;

    Consumer(Producer production) {           //constructor
        this.prod = production;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("sup");
        synchronized (prod.sb) {
      //wait till the notification is received from the Producer thread.
            try {
                System.out.println("waiting");
                prod.sb.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            }
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        System.out.println(prod.sb);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the *produce* and *consumer* **thread** to communicate with `notify()`

After the *pThread* is done with it's notification job, the *cThread* keeps on waiting for infinite amount of time.
Any idea, why the `prod.sb.wait();` is not being **noitified** by the `sb.notify();`

Comment: for synchronization you are better off using volatile of atomic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notifyAll()` is called before `wait()`, so the "signal" is lost. This is why you need a condition variable when using wait/notify.

```
boolean produced = false;
// In producer
produced = true;
asd.notifyAll();

// in consumer
while(!produced)
    wait();
```

Comment: Many thanks! Just one question: I didn't quite get the answer : **"Your're waiting on one object and notifying another"**

Comment: turns out, You **don't** even have to declare it as `volatile`  :)

Comment: That's true, no need for volatile.

Comment: I don't think you are waiting on the wrong object. But StringBuffer is thread safe. "String buffers are safe for use by multiple threads. The methods are synchronized".

Comment: @D4G4 You're not waiting on the wrong object (you'd get an `IllegalMonitorStateException` if you were), and although `StringBuffer` is thread-safe, it has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: It seems like a homework question, so before the instructor says: why are you synchronizing on a thread safe class? he should change it to StringBuilder or something else

Comment: @efekctive That's not right. Whether he's synchronizing on a thread-safe class or not is completely irrelevant. `synchronized(foobar)` does not mean that it will make `foobar` threadsafe.

Comment: yea, that's why I used `StringBuffer` in the first place. So was just clearing it. Thanks for the concern @Kayaman

Comment: If you want to synchronize on a thread safe class be my guest.

Comment: @efekctive If you're referring to the fact that if the thread-safe class has `synchronized` instance methods you might be competing for a lock, that's a different issue not for this question.

Comment: So the instructor is going to ask why the double synchronization? Doesn't seem too efficient hold a lock to access a method that has a builtin lock.  But have it your way. Logging off

Comment: @efekctive While it's true that the synchronized block is quite wide (it could just encapsulate the `notifyAll()`) it doesn't really make any difference. Especially the performance aspect is irrelevant, since if the thread is already holding the lock, there is no performance impact on calling the `synchronized append()`. You shouldn't say that something "doesn't seem effective", since it gives an impression that you don't know about its efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Just few comments regarding your code.

1. The consumer class has to know the producer class and this can be improved by introducing a third class that can buffer the message.
2. Did you consider using a Blocking queue or is it really what you want to do ?
   The producer is writing to the queue and the consumer has just to read from the queue without knowing who is actually writing into the queue. (Less dependency).
3. If in the future, you want to have multiple consumers for the same producer, how are you going to do ?

Let me know if you want a example of BlockingQueue (or similar)

Comment: It was just an example question.. I'm kinda new to this.. Having example of **BlockingQueue** will help :D and can you let me know about that **third class** as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Producer/Consumer using a queue to share the data in different threads :

```
/**
 * Consumer class.
 * It consume 
 * @author NourreddineHouari
 *
 */
public static class Consumer {

    /**
     * Input queue.
     */
    private BlockingQueue<String> intput;

    private Thread t;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * @param input Input queue to read from.
     */
    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> intput) {
        // Input queue
        this.intput = intput;

        //Start consuming
        t = new Thread(()->{
            while(true){
                // Read the data in the queue.
                String data;
                try {
                    // The take method will wait until something is
                    // available in the queue.
                    data = intput.take();
                    //Consume your input data
                    System.out.println("Consumer [" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + "] : " + data);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Start consuming
     */
    public void startConsuming(){
        //Start consumer process.
        t.start();
    }
}

/**
 * Producer class.
 * @author NourreddineHouari
 *
 */
public static class Producer {

    /**
     * Output queue.
     */
    private BlockingQueue<String> output;

    private Thread t;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> output) {
        this.output = output;
        Random r = new Random();
        //Start consuming
        t = new Thread(()->{
            while(true){
                try {
                    //Wait random time
                    Thread.sleep(500 + r.nextInt(1000));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                // Create dummy data
                String data = Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
                try {
                    this.output.put(data);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Start producing.
     */
    public void startProducing(){
        //Start producer process.
        t.start();
    }
}

/**
 *  Sample.
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Declare the queue
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

    // Producer
    Producer p = new Producer(queue);

    // Consumers
    Consumer c1 = new Consumer(queue); // The consumer and the producer don't know each others.
    //Consumer c2 = new Consumer(queue); //Uncoment for multiple consumer

    c1.startConsuming();
    p.startProducing();
    //c2.startConsuming(); //Uncoment for multiple consumers
}
```